# BIRT: multiple sub-groups (nested groups) in a table

Tags: grouping, birt

My dataset returns the following:

```
-------------------------------------------------
Month     Customer  Application  Operation  Count
-------------------------------------------------
Jun2011   Cust_1    App_1        Add        100
Jun2011   Cust_1    App_1        Update     100
Jun2011   Cust_1    App_2        Add        100
Jun2011   Cust_1    App_2        Update     100
Jun2011   Cust_2    App_1        Add        100
Jun2011   Cust_2    App_1        Update     100
Jun2011   Cust_2    App_2        Add        100
Jun2011   Cust_2    App_2        Update     100
Aug2011   Cust_1    App_1        Add        50
Aug2011   Cust_1    App_1        Update     50
Aug2011   Cust_1    App_2        Add        50
Aug2011   Cust_1    App_2        Update     50
Aug2011   Cust_2    App_1        Add        50
Aug2011   Cust_2    App_1        Update     50
Aug2011   Cust_2    App_2        Add        50
Aug2011   Cust_2    App_2        Update     50
-------------------------------------------------
```

Now using this dataset I need to create a report which has multiple groups in a single table (as shown below)

```
Expected Report Output:
----------------------------------------------------------
Month    BreakDown_Type   BreakDown    Operation    Count
----------------------------------------------------------
Jun2011
        Summary
                                       Add          400
                                       Update       400
        Customer Breakdown
                          Cust_1
                                       Add          200
                                       Update       200
                          Cust_2
                                       Add          200
                                       Update       200
        Application Breakdown
                          App_1
                                       Add          200
                                       Update       200
                          App_2
                                       Add          200
                                       Update       200
Aug2011
        Summary
                                       Add          200
                                       Update       200
        Customer Breakdown
                          Cust_1
                                       Add          100
                                       Update       100
                          Cust_2
                                       Add          100
                                       Update       100
        Application Breakdown
                          App_1
                                       Add          100
                                       Update       100
                          App_2
                                       Add          100
                                       Update       100
--------------------------------------------------------
```

In short the report has to display

```
- group-by(Month)
  - sub-group-by(Operation)
  - sub-group-by(Customer, Operation)
  - sub-group_by(Application, Operation)
```

I couldnt find a way to add multiple groups in a table. Is there any workaround to create such a report.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a workaround might be reorganizing dataset, if you can alter database query.

Query might look like

```
(Q1) UNION (Q2) UNION (Q3)
```

where `Q1` might be e.g.

```
SELECT 
    'Summary' AS BREAKDOWN_TYPE, 
    '' AS BREAKDOWN, 
    MONTH, 
    OPERATION, 
    COUNT
FROM OPERATIONS
```

`Q2`:

```
SELECT 
    'Customer Breakdown' AS BREAKDOWN_TYPE, 
    CUSTOMER AS BREAKDOWN, 
    MONTH, 
    OPERATION, 
    COUNT
FROM OPERATIONS
```

and `Q3` like `Q2` with `APPLICATION AS BREAKDOWN`.

This would change the grouping issue to the one, that BIRT can handle easily.